# What is the appropriate way to trigger spring-integration int-mail:inbound-channel-adapter?

Tags: java, spring-integration, pop3

First of all to clarify: I'm new to spring-integration.

I want to receive mails via an pop3-channel. I know and (think so) understand the poller mechanics. But I also want to trigger the question for new mail by a client-event. Can this be done by a Gateway or an event or a special service-locator?

Thank you brave helpers!

Comment: only one question post to here don't use single ticket as for multiple questions...

Comment: No, all qestions are OK in the context of issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't want to find similar solution, which I showed earlier, even on SO.
But as you say that you are newbie, so I just provide the solution for you.

Well, supose you have something like this now:

```
<int-mail:inbound-channel-adapter store-uri="pop3:foo"
                              channel="channel">
      <int:poller fixed-rate="60000"/>
</int-mail:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

On the background that configuration provides a bean for `Pop3MailReceiver`.
To get worked you solution you should change `<int-mail:inbound-channel-adapter/>` to this config:

```
<beans:bean id="pop3MailReceiver" class="org.springframework.integration.mail.Pop3MailReceiver"/>

<int:inbound-channel-adapter channel="getEmailsChannel" expression="''">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="60000"/>
</int:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:service-activator input-channel="getEmailsChannel" output-channel="processEmailsChannel"
                               expression="@pop3MailReceiver.receive()"/>
```

1. Of course, you should provide appropriate properties to the `Pop3MailReceiver`
2. Generic `<int:inbound-channel-adapter>` triggers your `Pop3MailReceiver` as it is in your case already invoking `<int:service-activator>`
3. `<int:service-activator>`, in turn, just **poll** mail messages from POP3.

One point to pay attention, that `MailReceiver#receive()` returns an array of mail messages, so maybe there is need to split it after receiving, to be consistent with `<int-mail:inbound-channel-adapter/>`.